# Will "protecting" my certificate require me to enter a password every time I sign an email?

Tags: certificates, email

I typically use my ECA certificate to sign my emails. I used to have a Symantec certificate but am now switching to an IdenTrust certificate. I am in the installation process and it is suggesting that I "protect" my certificate with a password (see screen shot below). If I do this will I have to enter a password every time I send an email?

[image]

Comment: Can you define "ECA certificate". Is that some proprietary thing?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calling their customer support and got the following answers:

- The password needs to be entered the first time an email is sent signed after Outlook opens. Outlook caches the password, so that if a password is associated with the certificate then it only needs to be entered once per session. Whenever Outlook is restarted then the first email sent will require entry of the password.
- Without the password a person could potentially copy the certificate off the computer and use it freely to impersonate me.